# Как закрыть от индексации лишь страницы вывода?

Tags: seo

Добрый день есть к примеру ссылка https://test.ru/shop. Ее требуется индексировать.

Но как закрыть от индексации страницы пагинации т.е https://test.ru/shop/page/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /shop/page
```